# Get related information MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a question about getting information from a MySQL database.

The context is as follows:

I have 2 tables, one called **brand** and the other **model** (about cars).

The **brand** table has 2 columns: *id* and *name*.
The **table** model has 3 columns: *id*, *brand*, *name*.

The brand column in the table model stores the corresponding brand id according the table brand.

For a consult, my standar query is:

```
SELECT * FROM model
```

... to get all the information in the table model, e.g.

```
id=1, brand=1, model=modelName.
```

What changes should I make to the query to get the brand name and not just its id, from a consult to the table model? e.g

```
id=1, brand=brandName, model=modelName
```

Comment: It's all about the joins... http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an inner join

```
SELECT model.id, brand.brandName, model.modelName 
FROM model
INNER JOIN brand on model.id = brand.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
SELECT m.id, b.name, m.name FROM model m, brand b WHERE m.brand = b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
SELECT brands.brand, model.* FROM brands JOIN  models ON brands.id=models.id
```

Comment: Join the same as inner join, only same words in different order. Perfect. Thanks!!